# convert from a `const char*[2]` to pair<string,string>

Tags: c++, string, stl, std-pair

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ application with a `const char*[2]` parameter that I would like to convert to a `std::pair< std::string, std::string >`. Is there a simple way to do this?

For example:

```
typedef std::pair< std::string, std::string > Group;
const char* a[ 2 ] = { "buzz", "foo" };
Group z = a; // ???

// a->first.c_str() == "buzz"
// a->second.c_str() == "foo"
```

Thanks,
PaulH

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want :

```
Group z(a[0], a[1]);
```

Comment: `pair` doesn't have any array/iterator/range constructors, so this is probably the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps

```
z = make_pair(std::string(a[0]), std::string(a[1]));
```